# This question is about time dilation but a bit different

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, time-dilation

See the image below-
[image]

Here I have decribed a scenario related to relativity theory. A spaceship is travelling at "V" velocity relative to a man standing on planet. The Spaceship's frame is named as A-frame while the man's frame is named B-frame. There are two clocks in spaceship named A and B separated with "d" distance. The light rays are moving towards spaceship as shown in image.

The velocity of light measured by spaceship is "C".
The man too observes that velocity of light is "C" relative to him.

From B-frame: Since the spaceship was moving towards light, the light takes lesser time to travel B to A than it takes when spaceship were at rest.

Let say d= 1 light sec

Then going by B-frame, the light takes 1 sec to travel d and since the light travels less distance than d, it takes time lesser than 1 sec to move from B to A(clocks).
Going by A-frame, the light travel B to A in 1 sec.

Man say it takes less than 1 sec while the astronaut says it takes exactly 1 sec.

How can we explain why this happened? Was there any time dilation causing the clock of astronaut to work faster and therfore showing larger time?

Because the rocket is moving, its time passes slower than man's. 1sec measured by rocket would be equal to more than 1sec of man's time. Fine but this is where problem comes in! The man said that time taken for that event, for which rocket took 1sec, is less than 1sec of man's time. So time would be not be slowed down for rocket in this case!

Comment: I don't understand what the "problem" is you want to be solved here - you just described a situation happening, you didn't pose any specific problem.

Comment: @ACuriousMind sorry for inconvenience

Comment: What you are not accounting for is the fact that 1 second on the rocket is not the same as 1 second for the man.  The man would see the rocket 1 second as something longer than 1 second from his frame of reference.

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. In frame B, d is less than 1 lightsecond due to length contraction, so the light takes less than 1 lightsecond to cross it. You worked this out correctly as far as I can see. What is the problem?

Comment: @foolishmuse i think i was unable to explain you. I can understand what you are saying but listen If £ assume that due to motion the clock on rocket got slower than clock of man then, from man's understanding his 1 sec is lesser than 1sec on rocket. But it doesn't explain the scenario I described in question. "1sec of rocket would be equal to more than 1sec of man.""The man himself knows that light  took less than 1sec of his own clock to move  B to A"  isn't both statements contradictory?

Comment: @ACuriousMind the question is that if time dilation is really occuring then, "is it rocket's time passing slower than man's?" In the end of question I said something totally opposite to that statement.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "how quickly" time is passing, it's just an effect of length contraction. You deduced that correctly. I don't get what you think there's left to explain.

Comment: @PredakingAskboss, if the people in each reference frame "compare notes", they will NOT agree on their observations.  There is no absolute reference frame, which is what the special theory of relativity is telling us.

Comment: I think you are sneaking in the idea of an absolute frame in your mind: *Because the rocket is moving, its time passes slower than man's*...according to whom?  For the rocket man, his clock is going exactly the right speed (e.g. a clock ticks every 1 sec).  For the earth man, the rocket man's clock *is* going slow.  For the rocket man, the earth man's clock is going slow. 
 Relativity tells us that anyone looking in his or her local surroundings will see everything behaving normally. Think about your problem again keeping that in mind.

Comment: One assumes that the speed of light is constant, and so the absorption duration changes (the frequency changes). Think of photons with a wavelength of meters in size; they take a while to absorb.

Comment: In what frame are you assuming that d = 1 light-second?

Comment: In A frame d = 1 light second.

Answer (score 4):

Given that you call the frames A and B, you ought to have used different labels for the clocks. That said...

The time taken for the light to move between Clock A and Clock B is always equal to d/c in the ship's frame. In the planet's frame, the time will be less if the ship is travelling towards the light, and more if the ship is travelling away from the light.

Time dilation refers to the fact that the time between two events that occur in the same place in one reference frame is always less than the time between the same two events in a frame in which they occur in different places. That does not apply to the scenario you have described- in your scenario there are two events (namely the light reaching Clock A and the light reaching Clock B) that occur at two different places in each frame.

Time dilation is just a special case of a more general effect known as the relativity of simultaneity. What that means is that where you have two events that happen at two different places, then the time between them is frame dependent. In the case you describe, the time between the two events will seem less in the planet frame if the rocket is moving towards the light, and more in the planet frame if the rocket is moving away from the light.

If there was a clock at points A and B on the rocket, then both clocks would always appear to be running slow in the planet frame. However, the time taken for the light to move between the clocks is not determined purely by the rate at which the clocks tick- *it is determined by the extent to which the clocks are out of synch.*

If the rocket is moving towards the light, the front clock will appear to be running behind the clock at the rear, so this will have the effect of making the time measured by the clocks for the light to go between them to be longer than it seems on the planet. If the rocket was moving away from the light in your diagram, the effect would be reversed, and the light would take less time to move between the clocks on the ship, according to them, than it did according to clocks on the planet. The difference between the two scenarios- in one of which the time seems longer on the ship and in the other of which it seems shorter- is due to the fact that the relativity of simultaneity means that the ships clocks are out of synch with the planet clocks, and the way in which they are out of synch reverses if the ship reverses direction.

Comment: But how is time dilation affecting the situation? I have read that for moving objects the time passes slowly but if I conclude the same here then, if less than 1 sec, let say 0.8sec is needed for light to travel B to A in frame B. Then less than 0.8sec of the A frame would be spent for the same task. But it is already given that time taken is 1sec not less than 0.8

Comment: Because the rocket is moving, its  time passes slower than man's. 1sec measured by rocket would be equal to more than 1sec of man's time. Fine but this is where problem comes in! The man said that time taken for that event, for which rocket took 1sec, is less than 1sec of  man's time.

Comment: I have extended my answer. Let me know if you are still unclear after reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Speed of light is "c" for both.

For A, supposing that the distance $d$ is measured in A frame, the time to travel between the two points is $t_A = \frac{d}{c}$

From A perspective, the time in B ticks slowly, but it is also the distance divided by $c$. But the distance $d$ is shorter for B due to lenght contraction $$t_B = \frac{t_A}{\gamma} = \frac{\frac{d}{c}}{\gamma} = \frac{\frac{d}{\gamma}}{c} = \frac{d'}{c}$$.

Comment: I don't understand why d is shorter for A frame. In its frame the d should not get contracted. Are you taking about d of B frame? Whatever, you said that time is slowed for rocket. Because the rocket is moving, its time passes slower than man's. 1sec measured by rocket would be equal to more than 1sec of man's time. Fine but this is where problem comes in! The man said that time taken for that event, for which rocket took 1sec, is less than 1sec of man's time.

Comment: @PredakingAskboss there is no absolute motion. In B frame, B is at rest, and the earth is moving. And being moving, the length $d$ is shorter.

Comment: Remove that planet thing. Just focus on frame A and frame B. Even if I think that time in frame A is passing slowly than in frame B(cause rocket is moving from B persepective), it gives incorrect information that time taken in frame B to see the same task is more than 1sec. Which instead should be less than that cause distance travalled in B perspective is less.

Comment: Did you understand what i am trying to say?

Comment: Sorry, but just now I realized that I changed A and B frame from the picture. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is to think that time dilation is the only effect of a change of frame.

When one changes frames in special relativity, there is a full change of variables which is called "Lorentz transformation" that **mixes time and space.**

For an observer in frame B, to compare the time on his clock with that at two **different** clocks A and B in frame A (you **really** should have chosen different letters....) involves mixing time and space in a **very complicated** way. Time dilation **is present**, but the fact that the two clocks are at different points in frame A is **by far** the dominant effect.

Only if the observer in frame B compares time in his frame with a **single** clock in frame A does time dilation apply **alone**.

You should look up "Lorentz transformation" in Wikipedia, for instance, and try to understand what happens when an observer in frame B compares times at different points in frame A.

I am sorry I cannot give you a better explanation without going into long developments that won't fit here.

But about the orders of magnitude : you mention a time of 0.8s as seen by the man in frame A. This means that the speed of the spaceship is 1/4 of the speed of light : as seen by the man in frame B, clock A moved forward 1/5 of the distance towards clock B, while the light covered 4/5 of the distance backwards from clock B to clock A, right? This is ignoring the length contraction, but the latter, at speed 1/4 of the speed of light is just about 3%, so my estimates are at least **roughly** correct.

But time dilation is also of about 3%. So you see, time dilation effect is only about one seventh of the main effect of 20%, due to the difference of **positions** of clocks A and B. When the calculations are done **precisely** in special relativity, including **both** length contraction **and** time dilation, everything will come out **precisely** OK.

But time dilation is completely dominated by the main effect that obviously shows that for the man **in frame B**, the time needed for the light to travel from clock A to clock B is less, by 20%, than 1s if the spaceship moves towards the light, and longer, by about 33%, if the spaceship moves away from the light, because A moves away from the old position of clock B by 1/3, during which time the light covers the full 4/3 of that distance from the old position of B and thus catches up with clock A, in the point of view of the man in frame B. (You **really, really should have used different letters !!!**)

Now just to give you a taste of the beauty of special relativity.

Because of length contraction, the spaceship looks 3% shorter to the man in frame B. So the times he observes are not 0.8s and 1.33s but rather about 0.77s and 1.29s. Now what is the **mean** of these two values ?

1.03s !

And here is time dilation of 3% for you !

Comment: "you mention a time of 0.8s as seen by the man in frame A. " No! the OP said it is seen by the man in B frame for whom the light seems to cover AB in 0.8sec

Comment: @ArsenalCreation That was a misprint. When speaking of "the man", I always meant the man in frame B. Thanks for pointing it out, I have corrected it now. This use of A and B for frames and clocks induces misprints... If you follow my logic, you can see that I never bother to compute a time difference in frame A  because the only relevant time in that frame is 1s.